# How to send a transition receipt along with a product identifier to my server?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, in-app-purchase

how to send a transition receipt along with a product identifier to my server using `HTTP POST` method? Should I have to encode the product identifier using base64?

I am getting this response:

> {"message" : "21002: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: propertyListFromString parsed an object, but there's still more text in the string. A plist should contain only one top-level object. Line number: 1, column: 2478.", "error" : 1}

even after I am encoding the transition receipt with base64 encoding...

This is what I am doing:

```
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"product_id=%@&receipt_data=%@",self.currentProductIdentifer,
[self.productReceiptData base64Encoding]];
NSData *bodyData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
  allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSAssert(bodyData!=nil,@"HTTP Body is empty !");

//posting the data to server 
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:inUrlString]
  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:inData];  //inData is http body(bodyData) created above 
 // create the connection with the request // and start loading the data 
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: Probably the error is in the server side

Comment: Maybe you could try to do without NSData *bodyData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
  allowLossyConversion:YES];?